# How to get all stocks from the specified URL in selenium headless mode?

Tags: selenium

Below I describe the issue I have.

**Description**

I want to simple fetch all stocks from the URL: https://www.di.se/bors/large-cap/
I do this from a very slow computer with a small screen (15"1) also zoom is set to 150% in Windows.
I want to do this in selenium headless mode by Java.

**Problem**

All stocks are not visible nor at screen or in inspect.
I try to fetch all stocks by the line:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
```

This command don't return all stocks. If I go the end of page and pageup to the end of the stock lists, I can see "getting more data" or in my language Swedish "hämtar mer data" at the end of the stock lists ie. Complete list with all stocks ends with Wihlborgs Fastigheter.

Inspect of current element gives:

```
<p class="instrument-table__load-more-info">Hämtar mer data...</p>
```

To update page with more stocks I have to scroll the page.

**Question**

How to fetch all stocks in headless mode in Java?

Comment: Please help me what to do, I'm stucked! 
I try to upload a picture what kind of messege I get but I'm not trusted. Picture can be found at: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMiR6oPyVBwNRab30oW_urBqg7BrK9T9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply download your data from the Yahoo Finance API?

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.optimize as sco
import datetime as dt
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
np.random.seed(777)
import yfinance as yf

start = '2018-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['MSFT','AAPL','GOOG']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    data = yf.download(ticker, start, end)

data = data.reset_index()
data
```

[image]