# How to scroll in selenium headless mode using Java?

Tags: selenium

**Description**

Because I don't yet have got any answer from mine post:
[How to get all stocks from the specified URL in selenium headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573361/how-to-get-all-stocks-from-the-specified-url-in-selenium-headless-mode)
I have to work on workaround to get progress on my work! Instead of trying to force an update on the site to get all stocks viewable (as described in my post) I will go to the end of page and then scroll up to force all stocks to get viewable (works fine when I do it manually).
All this MUST work in selenium headless mode!

**Problem**

I know how this can be implemented in selenium normal mode (not headless) but I can't get it to work in headless mode.
I think this line works both in normal and headless mode to go to the END of page:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

The issue I'm struggeling with is how to scroll up or pageup from the end of the page. I guess something like this will work:

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element to be returned like Storskogen"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", e);
```

I can't fetch the element "e", I can't get it work (NoSuchElementException is thrown). I have copied the xpath or css from Chrome without result though. I'm not even sure this will work in headless mode.

**Questions**

1. how to fetch element "Storskogen"?
2. is "scrollIntoView" scrolling working in headless mode?
3. how can pageup be implemented and working in headless mode?
4. how can I verify scrolling in headless mode?

It's okay to not answer every question. I use Java for implemention.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium headless window/display size by *default* is **800x600**.

So if you have a lot on your webpage, then you may end up with horizontal, as well as vertical scroll bars on the headless browser. Therefore, dependent on your webpage, the element you are after may not be drawn, hence you have to scroll up and down for it to appear.

To get the best results of scrolling up and down, you want to maximise your browser window. As you want to operate in headless mode, the actual browser will not be active, thus `driver.manage().window().maximize();` is not an option.

Do the following:

- Update your browser driver with a specific window size that will ensure no horizontal scroll bars. I have used the following for my BrowserDriverFactory as I test with multiple browsers: `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1280));` also you could manage a specific browser driver i.e. `chromedriver` with `options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");`

Then use JavascriptExecutor, as you mentioned above:

- Scroll down - `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");`
- Scroll up - `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollTop);");`